# Sending polkadot transaction with python script

Tags: polkadot

I am trying to send `polkadot transaction` with python script, using this rust code as a [reference](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-interaction-examples-rs/blob/main/src/bin/05_transfer_balance.rs)
but I'm having trouble to convert  `call.encode_to(&mut tmp)` with
`py-scale-codec`.

Comment: Could you please share the python script you're using?

Comment: You want to do a transfer? Why not look how to do it directly in python https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface#create-balance-transfer-extrinsic ?

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi hi, if ill be using this code what will happen with the nonce if i sending transactions in parallel?

and also in this way i will need to have my own node right? with db.
or maybe there is public Substrate node?

Comment: You can just manually set the nonce.